# Is it possible to generate elasticsearch reports from indexed content?

Tags: search, lucene, elasticsearch

I'm just getting used to using elasticsearch in our platform, and so far it's proven to be a superb move, but other than some built in stats I haven't found any reference to creating a report of sorts.  I guess the closest comparison would be facets, but it seems they need to be predefined in order to show stats for them.

What I would like to know is, is it possible to run reports such as:

1. What are the most popular phrases within the indexed content for the last 24 hours, week, etc.? This would be similar to what's used to produce Word/Tag Clouds, but without relying on user input (common search terms for example) as a source.
2. Can facets be suggested rather than specified based on the most popular phrases for a particular search term(s)?  i.e. If someone searches for the term "Music" and the most popular phrases including "Music" are things like "Music Awards" or "Electronic Music", can those facets be returned without designing them explicitly into the initial request?

As you can see what I'd like to know if we can gain any analytics from the indexed content, not just explicit results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For these types of reports and analytics of data in elasticsearch you may want to try Kibana3 http://three.kibana.org/. This will only work if your data has a timestamp as that is a requirement for analyzing data in Kibana. Tool is very flexible and I believe will give you the insights about your data you are looking for.