# Boosting an elasticsearch result based on a boolean field value

Tags: php, lucene, elasticsearch, elastica

I'm getting a lot of "static" when searching for the correct way to boost a result when a "Boolean" field type is TRUE, most results are talking about boolean searches.

**N.B. We're using the php elastica library** but if you can only provide json that's fine, I can manage from that.

I have an index with 5 fields where we have some built in boosting going on as you can see here:

```
array(
    'article_id' => array('type' => 'string', 'include_in_all' => FALSE),
    'subject' => array('type' => 'string', 'include_in_all' => TRUE, 'boost' => 8),
    'summary' => array('type' => 'string', 'include_in_all' => TRUE, 'boost' => 5),
    'content' => array('type' => 'string', 'include_in_all' => TRUE, 'boost' => 3),
    'media'  => array('type' => 'boolean', 'include_in_all' => FALSE),
    'pub_date'  => array('type' => 'date', 'include_in_all' => FALSE)
)
```

I'm also successfully boosting the results at a variety of levels via the `pub_date` field based on age using the `addShould()` method on a `\Elastica\Query\Bool()` query object.

What I would like to do now is boost results further where `media` is TRUE.

Can someone tell me how to add the appropriate boost for just the `media` field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are different ways to boost your results, have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12427449/elasticsearch-boosting-relevance-based-on-field-value) to know more. Your usecase seems easy, you could do it at index time but I would rather do it at query time, just adding a should clause to your [bool query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/bool-query/) and giving a proper boost to it if needed:

```
{
    "bool" : {
        "must" : {
            ...
        },
        "should" : [
            {
                .....
            },
            {
                "term" : { "media" : "TRUE" }
            }
        ],
    }
}
```

The new clause would be optional, but it makes the score of the matching documents higher. If necessary you can add a specific boost to it, its value mainly depends on the other clauses.

Comment: Thanks @javanna, it was the `term` type that I was looking for, I didn't know what type of comparison object to use when boosting and looking for `TRUE`, so this is perfect, I thought it would be something simple!

Comment: just wondering if you have any insight on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16989856/is-it-possible-to-generate-elasticsearch-reports-from-indexed-content

Comment: @oucil @ javanna wouldn't this fetch results where media is true but the must query is not matched?

Comment: @khizerbajwa been a while since I've looked at this but no, the bool is a mix of must and should, the must has to be satisfied to apply it, the should does not. Putting the term in should will give it an extra boost when it exists, but doesn't restrict all results to it.